# PC works fine, motherboard LED blinks when it's off

Tags: motherboard, led

I had left my desktop PC with an ASUS motherboard plugged in at night (I generally unplug it when I'm not using it) and I noticed it's motherboard LED was blinking. I unplugged it, waited 10 seconds and plugged it in again, but still it blinks.

What does it mean?

Comment: That's normal and by (the manufacturer's) design. It means it's detecting power.

Comment: unplug the network cable and it may stop

Comment: @JohnnyVegas it stopped indeed. What does it mean? Do some motherboards have like a network cable led which is supposed to behave like this or do I have to worry?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Wake on Lan - A protocol where a fully switched off computer with a network cable plugged in can be switched on by the use of a 'magic packet'.